# Getting a NullPointerException but printing the object returns a both a memory refence and a null value

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to make a program that simulates NFA's, I have state objects and an NFA object (named machine). The state objects refrence other states (like a tree data structure but without hierarchy) right now the NFA object only defines the starting state and the rest are linked from there.

The problem comes when I try to assign the NFA (named machine)'s start state to the search variable (type State). When I later try to use this object to move through out the NFA it gives a null pointer error. When debugging (shown by print statements) it seems that assigning the variable seems to work correctly but more strange: when I print the object later it prints both a memory refence and a null value.

```
System.out.println(machine.getStart()); //prints out State@6bc7c054
search = machine.getStart(); //assigns the starting state of the NFA to search variable
System.out.println(search); //prints out State@6bc7c054

... (there is no code related to search variable in this chunk)

System.out.println(search + " last ref");//prints State@6bc7c054 last ref    (and also)
                                                  null last ref
search = search.move(sym);//line that gives NullPointerException
```

Any thoughts on whats going wrong here are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

My answer is obvious but, if 4 lines where printed, then you should have 4 `println` instruction (or an `"\n"` in one of them), check in the hidden chunk if you haven't any `println`.

As for me, the most probable is that, in the hidden chunk you've a `println` statement that prints well your `search + "last ref"` and an other statement that sets `search` to `null`.
If I'm right, then your last `println` is printing the `null last ref`, and you'll have `NullPointerException` if you try to act on `search`.